Do published articles go through detailed check? And often require a extra data to be submitted
I have published a paper and one month after publication my supervisor is telling me that I should prepare a bunch of statistical tests for that published paper, even though usually in my area (materials) we don’t need heavy statistical analysis. He said that it will be checked by someone.
I don’t understand if the paper went though peer review ( I had 4 reviewers) and got accepted and finally published, why I need to go back to it and prepare for possible requested corrections. So, my main question is: how often did your published works require corrections raised by the readers?

Why not ask your supervisor? If you don't understand why someone is asking you to do something, the natural thing -- one would assume -- is to have a conversation about it!

May it be that this has nothing to do with the journal or readers? For example, the request may come from your university (e.g. being an internal requirement for a PhD), or from a funding agency etc?

This is not common. You might get it if there's a challenge of some kind - a comment for example (see this for what a comment is in this context), an allegation of misconduct, a peer review failure such that the journal is thinking of retracting your article, and so on. Informally, there might also be people emailing the authors about parts they don't understand or do not seem correct.
It's not clear from your description why exactly your supervisor wants you to do the statistical tests. It could simply be extending the work, leading to a different paper. Ultimately, asking your supervisor about the point of the tests is probably the most productive thing to do.
